# Jupyter reports "bad interpreter" following Homebrew Python update

Tags: python, ipython, homebrew, jupyter

Since updating my Python using Homebrew

```
jupyter --version
```

gives

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

which makes some sense, since there's no longer a Python at `/usr/local/.../python2.7`. But I don't see any way to repair this.

Prior to updating Python, I there was a Python there, and the Homebrew's symlinked `python` pointed there, but now `which -a python` gives

```
/usr/local/opt/python@2/libexec/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

which corresponds to what I want, and are, respectively

- Homebrew's 2.7, which is found because it is on `PATH`
- Homebrew's symlinked 3.6.x
- Apple's old Python

I've also `brew link --overwrite --force python2` [for good measure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49099773/656912), but this has no effect.

How do I get `jupyter` to find and use the Python 2.7 on my `PATH`?

Comment: Why not use a virtual env or condo env?

Comment: @bigbounty: I'm not using one for this. Assume none.

Comment: homebrew recently pointed python formula to python3.x, have you tried reinstall jupyter with `pip2`?

Comment: How did you install jupyter? If with homebrew, re-install.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works for me, its just to link Jupiter with the correct Python version.

```
 rm '/usr/local/bin/jupyter'
 brew link --overwrite jupyter
 brew link --overwrite --dry-run jupyter
 brew unlink jupyter && brew link jupyter
```

Answer (score 7):

Homebrew moved the Python 2 to be keg-only, using the `python@2` formula. The `jupyter` formula has been updated accordingly, please upgrade it:

```
brew update && brew upgrade jupyter
```

Note that the Python 2 binary is now only available as `python2`, the `python` binary, if installed by Homebrew, is Python 3.

If you installed it with pip, link the Python 2 binary and re-install jupyter using `pip2`:

```
brew link -f python@2
/usr/local/bin/pip2 install -U jupyter
```

You'll end up with a `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` file that starts with the line `#!/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: I use pip and have done both steps you suggest to no avail. Now (I *may* have deleted it) `jupyter` is missing ("jupyter: command not found"). So I need to get the executable back. How do I do that (with pip) so I can try those steps again?

Comment: @orome: I can't reproduce this. `pip2 install jupyter` produced a `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` binary.

Comment: Try deleting or moving `jupyter` first. I don't have `jupyter` in `/usr/local/bin/` (though there's a bunch of other `jupiter-...` stuff there).

Comment: @orome I did. I installed from scratch and reinstalled after deleting some key files.

Comment: @orome: out of curiosity: why not use `brew install jupyter`? I don’t know for certain how that’ll interact with the packages installed by `pip` though, and Jupyter has a fairly large number of dependencies.

Comment: Weird. For me no `pip@2` (no mater how I invoke it) will install the `jupyter` binary. What's your (Python relevant) path; do you have a `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: No, I have no `PYTHONPATH`, I made sure to use a clean environment when testing. The binary is `pip2`, not `pip@2`.

Comment: Yes. By `pip@2` I meant "the pip for Python 2 by any path" (that's what I thought it meant): `pip`, `pip2` `/usr/local/bin/pip2` etc. all of which are the same for me.

Comment: `pip` is not the same as `/usr/local/bin/pip2`. Not with the current `python@2` homebrew formula. Make sure you check what pip you have with the `-V` switch, which tells you where pip installs to.

Comment: For me it’s the same.

Comment: @orome: if `/usr/local/bin/pip` and `/usr/local/bin/pip2` are the same, then that's a strong indication your Homebrew setup for Python is broken. Please run `brew doctor`, fix the issues that finds, make sure you have updated (`brew update`) and upgraded both the Python 2 and 3 formulas (`brew upgrade python python@2`). Then check again. `/usr/local/bin/pip` is tied to the Python 3 binary.

Comment: Brew is fine (`doctor` reports "Your system is ready to brew.", all Pythons are updated and upgraded; and I got where I am by following the instructions it gave for setting up 2 as the default).