# Jupyter throws "bad interpreter" error from homebrew installation

Tags: jupyter, homebrew, python-3.10

Assumptions:

VScode editor
Installing natively (no virtual environments)
zsh on Mac
python 3.10

So, my issue is that every time I use:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get an error like this:

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: bad interpreter: /usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory
```

yet I am running these commands as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097097/jupyter-reports-bad-interpreter-following-homebrew-python-update) as well as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946157/jupyter-notebook-bad-interpreter-error-message)

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/jupyter'
 brew link --overwrite jupyter
 brew link --overwrite --dry-run jupyter
 brew unlink jupyter && brew link jupyter
```

```
brew uninstall jupyter
brew install jupyter
brew link --overwrite jupyter
```

I've even tried editing the JSON file to point to 3.10 python version but it's not working.

I want to do this in homebrew as opposed to just using pip3.10 or switching to a conda environment. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Homebrew's `jupyterlab` formula requires Python 3.9. Source: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jupyterlab

Eventually, it will be migrated to Python 3.10. The list of formulae that are currently being migrated can be found here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+label%3Apython-3.10-migration